# How do I early return in declarative macros and infer the return type?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-decl-macros

I have a macro, which just generates an instance of a struct, as below:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    () => {{
        let baz_val = baz();
        
        let bar_val = match bar() {
            Ok(val) => val,
            Err(err) => {
                return Err(err);
            }
        };
        
        Ok(Foo(baz_val, bar_val))
    }};
}
```

As you can see, I do an early return in macro depending on `bar()` function's result. That's, however, resolves as an error, saying:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:24
   |
23 |                 return Err(err);
   |                        ^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found enum `Result`
...
32 |     let foo_val = foo!();
   |                   ------ in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                   found enum `Result<_, String>`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `foo` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

[Here's also the permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=47c578886a43b9bada17103e59803c16) that has full minimum reproducible sample.

I think the problem here is type inference. I'd like to return an instance of `FooResult` in the sample, but the macro cannot infer it.

So, how do I early return and infer/define the return type in the declarative macros?

---

## Environment

- rustc 1.55.0

Comment: `return` doesn't return from the macro. It returns from the function where you expand the macro. And that function returns `()`.

Comment: I am sure you have more complex situation but incase it helps you can solve it without `closure` & "`return` keyword" : [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4a71ffb852d1d0abcd713acd6a6ff849)

Comment: @ÖmerErden | In my case, readability matters, so I'll opt-out continue nesting inside `bar_val` (ofc if that's what you're referring to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` is used in functions not in macros. For the expected behaviour you can wrap the macro into a closure and call it inmediatly:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    () => {{
        (|| {
        let baz_val = baz();

        let bar_val = match bar() {
            Ok(val) => val,
            Err(err) => {
                return Err(err);
            }
        };

        Ok(Foo(baz_val, bar_val))
        })()

    }};
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=60693dc6fc6cd44d1d4dd6e10b7ff0a7)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Netwave's answer is to use the nightly-only feature `label-break-value` as such:

```rust
#![feature(label_break_value)]

macro_rules! foo {
    () => {'foo: {
        let baz_val = baz();

        let bar_val = match bar() {
            Ok(val) => val,
            Err(err) => {
                break 'foo Err(err);
            }
        };

        Ok(Foo(baz_val, bar_val))
    }};
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4dd4602cae768ac3fbe1d9ff3e1c3fff)

I believe this feature was designed explicitly to be able to "return" from arbitrary blocks, which is pretty much your situation.